# Angular 2 RC 1 Not working in IE 9

Tags: angularjs

I am seeing this error message in console:
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'requestAnimationFrame'

Anyone seeing this?

Comment: Yes, node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js,node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js,node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js Using these with angular lib.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6111

Comment: I tried that and it resolved that issue but then it started throwing this error: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Unable to get property 'contains' of undefined or null reference. This is generated in the template EXCEPTION: Error in App/Profile/longprofile.html:0:8. Works fine in other browsers.

Comment: If you solve the question that is asked here, you should post the answer and open a different question if you have a new error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a polyfill for IE9, it's a JS thing.

Add this to your `<head>`

`<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js?features=requestAnimationFrame"></script>`